# What's a good book for a beginner who wants to learn about Sound on the Computer?

Tags: audio

I want to learn how mp3, wav, mid, or whatever format is represented on the computer, but I don't even have the vocabulary to google with. Can you name a few to get me started?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduction to Computer Music:

http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP000962.html